# Pool light turns off sporadically

Tags: electrical, light, pool

I have a pool light that will turn off and on at random times. I thought it was a bad light, so I bought a new one and that did not fix anything. So, I took out my electrical non-contact tester and found that there was no electricity being read from the socket connection point. I then noticed there was some rust on the screw holding the connection terminal. I scraped that off and got it so that the electrical tester read as expected. However I still couldn't get a light to turn on. I took out my multimeter and of course the screen on that is on the fritz, but it does read something (maybe in the 100s). I ended up giving up to do some research, but when I put everything back together it worked when I flipped the switch - however a few minutes later it did not turn on. I have read that it could be a GFCI tripping, but that wouldn't turn itself back on. So, I am a bit baffled - how do I read electricity, but the light bulb doesnt react....Any tips/hints/ideas/etc?

Comment: Loose connection somewhere. Or timer somewhere (it's common for pool lights to be on a timer so they run only at night).

Comment: Not a timer as it is a simple on off switch and it does it at random intervals. Loose connection would mean the power goes out altogether, but the electric tester reads as constant..

Comment: It it's turning off, it's losing power. The only question is _where_ it is losing power..

Comment: There could be a timer, or other secondary switching mechanism, in series with the "simple" switch you're aware of. Or there could be a loose connection "downstream" of where you've tested, such as at the bulb socket. "If it happens, it must be possible."